# Game of Life generation procession algorithm

Tags: algorithm, c, game-of-life

I've tried to make Game of Life in console and this is the algorithm I used to generate new generation:

```
void processGeneration() {
    population = 0;
    int neighbors;
    int tempGrid[ROWS][COLS];
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == -1) {
                continue;
            }
            neighbors = countNeighbors(i, j);
            if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                if (neighbors == 3) {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
                }
            } else if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
                if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3) {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == -1) {
                continue;
            }
            if (tempGrid[i][j] == 1) {
                population++;
            }
            grid[i][j] = tempGrid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit uncertain if what I did was right, so could you check the algorithm? Also, `grid` is the grid where I save the cells in and I just use `tempGrid` to change the values and then copy them to the grid.

```
int countNeighbors(int row, int col) {
    int neighbors = 0;
    for(int i = row - 1; i < row + 2; i++) {
        for(int j = col - 1; j < col + 2; j++) {
            if (i == row && j == col) {
                continue;
            }
            if (i > -1 && j > -1 && i < ROWS && j < COLS) {
                neighbors += grid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Have you not tested it yourself?

Comment: @Jamal it's actually my first time ever trying to implement the game of life, although I searched for common shaped generated by this, I can recognize /some/ shapes produced with my algorithm but I just want to be sure of it

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithms looks correct, I could not find any obvious mistakes.

On the other hand, I have a suggestion towards the readability of your code:
Use more functions that tell the reader what you're doing right now. For example, instead of saying

```
if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
    if (neighbors == 3) {
        tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
    } else {
        tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

you could write:

```
int cellIsDead(int x, int y) { return grid[i][j] == 0; }
int hasEnoughNeighboursToComeToLife(int x, int y) { return countNeighbors(x, y) == 3 }
void makeCellComeAlive(int x, int y) { tempGrid[i][j] = 1; }


if (cellisDead(i, j) && hasEnoughNeighboursToComeToLife(i, j)) {
    makeCellComeAlive(i, j);
}
```

Yes, this takes more time and also probably some global variables (although `grid` already looks global, so no issue), but it is a) easier to read (see how it almost reads like the rules of the game?) and b) easier to prove to be correct using unit tests. And any decent compiler will inline these function calls at compile time, so no runtime overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator in a few places:

```
if (neighbors == 3) {
    tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
} else {
    tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
}
```

can be shorten to:

```
tempGrid[i][j] = (neighbors == 3) ? 1 : 0;
```

The function `countNeighbors` is not efficient: you are scanning 9 values and discarding 5 of those.  You should instead hard code the four values. [**Oops**: I actually misunderstood the rules.  See comments.]

There is also the business with `-1`.  I assume you are using this to denote the boundaries.  It's not clear to me if this trick simplifies or complicates the code.  If you don't use `-1` values, you would only need to modify `countNeighbors` to correctly deal with edges and corners.  That method would be more complex.

In the following paragraph, I am proposing an alternative design.  I am not claiming it is better.  Instead of having `grid[][]` and `tempGrid[][]`, you could have `grid[][]` and `neighborCounts[][]`.  You call some method to fill the `neighborCounts` grid only once.  That method would deal separately with corners, edges and inner cells.  After you have completed `neighborCounts` you can directly modify `grid`.

Comment: why its not efficient ? not sure I understand, also I just though of something neighbors += grid[i][j]; in countNeighbors will cause problems if one of the cells is a border right ? need to check if it's -1 and it it is use continue before adding to the neighbors

Comment: Yes, the loop does look inefficient, but I'm pretty sure a compiler will unroll it and get rid of the one case where you are checking for the current position.

Comment: before doing it in a loop I just made a function that gets i and j and checks if in grid[i][j] cell is alive and I just sent the 8 different neighbors each time to the function, is it more effective ? Also what about what I said about this : "also I just though of something neighbors += grid[i][j]; in countNeighbors will cause problems if one of the cells is a border right ? need to check if it's -1 and it it is use continue before adding to the neighbors"

Comment: I'm sorry.  I had misunderstood the rules: I thought only the four "main" neighbors were checked (up, down, left, right).  So your neighbor scanning algorithm was not inefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second comment.  What you are currently doing seems OK.

Comment: @toto2 but what if one of the neightbors is a border cell ? meaning it hold a value of -1 so I don't check if it's a border and I just do neighbors += the value and that could cause the neighbor value to be false at some cases, am I right ? hopefully you understand what I mean

Comment: There is no error.  Corners are unlikely to have 2 or 3 active neighbors since they have a total of 3 neighbors.  A completely different implementation would be to assume periodic boundary conditions.  It is as if the 2-dimensional grid is a torus.  There are no boundaries in that case.  For example the neighbors of (0, 0) are not only (1,  0), (1, 1) and (0, 1), but also (n-1, 0), (n-1, n-1), etc.  It is not better than the fixed boundary you used, but simply a different problem.

Comment: @toto2 Here I made a painting showing what I mean : http://i60.tinypic.com/1zefvpj.png                            The cell with the question mark (?) is 0 and you want to find if to bring him to life based on the number of his neighbors, so you have 3 neighbors BUT looking and my countNeighbors method I'm pretty sure that it'll SCAN the border cells and it'll do this : neighbors += grid[i][j];   and instead of ending up with 3 neighbors like intended I'll end up with -1 neighbors. Am I correct ?

Comment: @toto2 part2 of comment :                                     I think I should change this : if (i > -1 && j > -1 && i < ROWS && j < COLS) to this : if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i < ROWS - 1 && j < COLS - 1)